# Populating data to a nested Dictionary Collection

Tags: c#

I have a collection 
`List<Employee>` which contain Properties like

`Name` ,`EmployeeID`,`Address`,`JobTitle` and so on

For every employee there are few column which changes and based upon these few columns i need to update my Active Directory.

So i thot of creating a `isEditable` field for each column which will signify whether the column has changed or not for a particular employee . But it turns out that i need to create this field for all the columns and the number of columns also changes frequently .

So I came up with nested dictionary collection

```
 Dictionary<int, Dictionary<object, bool>>
```

which will store the `Employee ID` as the `key` and the `object` type will store all the `column names` and `bool` by default will be `false`

But i don't know how to populate the above nested collection with `List<Employee>` Collection .

This is what i have tried till now

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<object, bool>> _isEditable = new Dictionary <int, Dictionary<object, bool>>();

foreach (var item in _empColl )
{
   foreach (var type in _empColl .GetType ().GetProperties ())
   {
       _isEditable.Add  (item.EmployeeID ,dict.Add (type.Name,false));
   }
}
```

But its throwing error .I'm trying to get the metadata (column names ) from the `_empColl` for each `EmployeeID`

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object,bool>>.Add(int, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object,bool>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Why don't you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `Employee` class to get the list of changed properties?

Comment: dict.add() is of type "void", you may not use it in _isEditable.Add().

Comment: @Dennis : I can't use that because my Property is not changing .I'm trying to compare 2 collection which  have identical columns and for each row ,the columns which are differing i not to make a note

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ below to get the result:

```
 var _isEditable = _empColl.ToDictionary(item => item.EmployeeID,
                                         item => item.GetType()
                                                  .GetProperties()
                                                  .ToDictionary(pro => pro.Name, 
                                                                pro => false));
```